# Which one doesn't fit in?

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

I will give you five nouns and you have to find the one which doesn't belong with the others. Sounds easy? Try it!

> - woman, child, police, sun, car
> - ireland, island, goblin, citizen, sheep
> - spy, adventurer, witch, convention, thief
> - network, computer, mousepad, keyboard, wire

In your answer you have to:

- tell me which one doesn't belong
- explain the pattern, which is the same for all four sets
- make up your own example with five nouns

Have fun!

If you're stuck - here's a hint ...

> The pattern works in every language.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: I have a question. Does the pattern vary for all 4 questions? If so, when we make up our example, what would make it a valid example?

Comment: @Sid The pattern is always the same, if you mean that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Police, Ireland, convention, network

Explanation:

> They are abstract concepts, they don't refer to actual objects, made out of atoms. I'm putting Ireland as the second one assuming that you mean it as the state of Ireland, rather than the island itself.

New set:

> Rock, pen, desk, chair, **shadow**

Comment: You got it. I too was worried about the word "Ireland".

Comment: Are you saying that goblins are real?

Comment: Ireland is a country.

Comment: Concepts are abstract by their very nature. And what exactly is not material about Ireland? It's also the proper name of an island. If anything, mother, citizen, island and sheep are abstract inthat they are names for generic concepts, not for material things, unless you call sets material.

Comment: @MartinSmith: No, but if they existed, they would be a concrete object.

Comment: +Ashwin Schumann As Runemoro said, Ireland is just a name for a country, not the island itself. A mother is touchable, I can touch an island (by touching the ground) also a sheep.

Comment: I would say citizen is in the same boat then. It's something we call people but not an actual thing

Comment: Well, the state is actually  called "Republic of Ireland", not "Ireland", while the _island_ is indeed called "Ireland". Just google it. And if materiality is defined by touch, then what about the sun? "Oh, you can see it." Can you see a mother though? Nope, because it's a concept. And "sheep" and "sheep" are two things very different: the one is a concept, the other a function.

Comment: If spy, adventurer, witch, and thief all count, why doesn't police? These are all ways of describing a person based on their actions or vocation. Just because it doesn't specify police[(wo)man]? Well, they are just "police" in plural form.

Comment: @feelinferrety: "Police" isn't the same as policeman. If I saw a policeman I wouldn't call him "a police".

Comment: It's not a dig at you as an answerer. It's a criticism of the puzzle for having this be the intended solution. I don't believe "police" deserves to be singled out, nor should "citizen" fit in as other commenters have mentioned. The puzzle has a decent concept, but the execution needs work.

Answer (score 5):

woman, child, police, sun, car

> Does not belong: 'Sun' because Under one Sun there are many women, children, police, cars but the sun is ONE

ireland, island, goblin, citizen, sheep

> Does not belong: 'Ireland' because In one Ireland there are many islands, golins, citizens, sheep but Ireland is ONE

spy, adventurer, witch, convention, thief

> Does not belong: 'Convention' because In ONE convention there may be may spies, adventurers, witches, thieves, but the convention is ONE

network, computer, mousepad, keyboard, wire

> Does not belong: 'Network' because In one network there can be many computers, mousepads, keyboards, wires but network is ONE

My own example with five nouns: body, vein, shoe, bone, bacteria

> A body can have many veins, bones, bacteria and can wear two (human) or  more(animals) shoes but the body ONE

Comment: If this answer is correct then the Hint is misleading, hint should be:'Umbrella'

Comment: This is a good answer, but I don't think that the hint is misleading: It just tells you to look at the meaning of the words, not at their representation in one language. (So it's more of a clarification than a hint. Given that the question is rather broad, this clarification should probably be a part of the question, not a hint.)

Comment: Unfortunately not the answer I wanted. But cool theory.

Comment: There are many goblins in Ireland?! Remind me never to go there.

Comment: @edderiofer, don't tell me I didn't warn you, especially about conventions :D

Answer (score 4):

Answer

> Sun, goblin, witch, network
> all not terrestrial
> Other words are terrestrial

Explanation

> goblin and witch are spirits, fake
> Sun is on earth
> network is not something you can touch and it uses Satellite

Example

> Bride, Groom, Father, Mother, Elf

Result

> Elf is an imaginary being

Comment: You're near the mark but not the answer I want. You're getting closer ...

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> police, sheep, convention, network. 
>  
>  All can refer to groups (of animals or people). The other nouns are all singular objects.
>
>  Example: 
>  
>  hammer, tower, highway, **audience**, chair

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer:

> police, sheep, spy, wire

Explanation:

> On each line there are two pairs of words which has the same length (e.g. pair 1: "woman", "child"; pair 2: "sun", "car"), and the word without pair (e.g. police) is the odd and doesn't fit in.

Another example as is requested by quest:

> car, egg, door, word, alien

Where this word is odd:

> alien

Comment: That's sheer coincidence and not the "right" answer. Sorry.

Comment: I liked this answer, but it fails on `network, computer, mousepad, keyboard, wire` - letter lengths are 7, 8, 8, 8, 4.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete stretch...

Answer:

> police
>  
> sheep
>  
> spy
>  
> network

Pattern:

> If you place the number of vowels in each word (including "y") over the length of that word and reduce, you end up with one fraction in each set that has a unique denominator.
>  
>  For instance, the first line:
>  
> Vowels/Length: 2/5, 1/5, 3/6, 1/3, 1/3
>  
> Reduced: 2/5, 1/5, 1/2, 1/3, 1/3
>  
> 5 and 3 each appear in a denominator twice. 2 only appears once.
>  
>  Reducing is necessary for the last line but works for all of them.

New Set:

> bear, ant, pear, trees, forest

Comment: Wow, unfortunately it's not the answer I want. It's way easier. xD

Answer (score 0):

[Police, ireland, convention, network]

- Police - only plural
- Ireland - only proper noun
- Convention - only one not describing a person
- network - only not referring to specific singular tangible item